# How to change color of H4 when hovering

Tags: html, css

I have a H4 tag and I want to color the label black when I hover over it.

```html
<li id="calendarlink">
  <h4 class="calLink" style="font-weight: bold;">Calendar</h4>
</li>
```

Comment: What label are you talking about?

Answer (score 3):

Your question isn't very clear. But if you want your h4 to turn to a color when you hover over your h4 text, you can use the css:hover selector.

```
h4:hover {
   color: red;
}
```

Something like that.